# Xcode subproject cannot find its own header files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, sdk

I have an sdk that is added to my project as a subproject in xcode. My main project's classes can import all the header files successfully into the code by using

```
#import "Filename.h"
```

because I added the sdk directory to my Header Search paths in the build settings of my main project.

However, the problem is that the classes of my sdk can't successfully import each other unless they are in the same directory. In my case, this is a problem because my sdk has folders within it with header files that the files in the main sdk folder want to import. As a result, I receive the error:

```
'Filename.h' cannot be found
```

when files in the main sdk folder try to import header files nested in deeper folders in the sdk. When I tried to move all the files into the main directory (I'm fine with sacrificing organization for functionality), the original error remained and I got two more errors:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/.../MainProjectFolder/SDKFolder/NestedFolder/Filename.m'

clang: error: no input files
```

It seems to know where to look for the files but the other files still can't access it.
Does anyone have any ideas to help?
Thanks, any help is appreciated!

Comment: UPDATE: I figured out that i had to add the search paths to my main directory rather than my subproject directory. However, now I am receiving the error: 
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_LoginService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GettingStartedViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ProfileService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GettingStartedViewController.o
where the view controller is my main project's and the service files are in the sdk. Any ideas on fixing this?